# How to make a combobox with style(CBS_DROPDOWN) non-editable?

Tags: winapi, combobox, mfc

I want to make a combobox with style (`CBS_DROPDOWN`) as non-editable. I googled for sometime and everywhere I have seen suggesting to change the combobox style from `CBS_DROPDOWN` to `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` . I am supposed to use a combobox of `CBS_DROPDOWN` only and this should be non-editable.

Is there a way to get this done? If any, can anyone kindly help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: What's the actual problem with using `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` ??

Comment: I'm pretty sure, noone asked you to use a particular control style, but rather required you to implement certain functionality. Since you aren't telling us what you **really** want, you can't expect to get much help.

Comment: It could be that the behavior is dynamic based on some other state, e.g. in one mode you can only select items from the list, but in another mode, allow users to be able to enter a value (or pick from the list), e.g. a picker vs. a picker/creator???

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, there is the `CBS_DROPDOWNLIST` style available. Using this style is the normal way to make the edit control read-only, as there is no edit field at all.

If you insist in using the `CBS_DROPDOWN` style, you can use [CComboBox::GetComboBoxInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6k2dt8t.aspx) to get the HWND of the edit field, and then you can send it a [EM_SETREADONLY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761655.aspx) message, or you can also subclass it to intercept user input.

This is a bare answer without knowing what you really want to do and expect.